# How to make functions with int parameters don't accept boolean values?

Tags: php

For example, the following code runs ok:

```
<?php

function test(int $p) {
    var_dump($p);
    return $p;
}

test(1);
test(true);
```

Live test: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c015a6c98a2efb8f5a335a1b4cc802488786203f

Is there any way to make it doesn't accept boolean values?

Comment: @B001ᛦ ah! That would make my answer redundant^^ :p will remove once dupe is accepted^ :)

Comment: no worries, I always love your answers @treyBake

Comment: @B001ᛦ thank you for that motivation! :D

Comment: @treyBake if you put `foo('1')` in `b.php` it won't show any error unless you specify `declare(strict_types=1);` inside `b.php` as well